# Directive not loading HTML string as actual HTML on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-bind-html

I am new to angularjs and using this directive as below. When this directive gets loaded on HTML file, it should treat these HTML as actual HTML rather than string but it is not working. I am using angular 1.4.7 version.

Please help!! I am adding below HTML as String because I am getting that HTML as String from service dynamically. So this is just example that I am adding here to see how can we display html value on angularjs html if it is coming as string.

```
angular.module('my.directive', [])
    .directive("myDirective", function(){
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            scope: false,
            template: "<div class='con'>"+
            "<div>'<p><i><strong>some text</strong></i></p>'</div>"+
            "</div>"
        };
    });
```

I have tried multiple ways to fix it here but no luck. I have tried using "ng-bind-html-unsafe" and "ng-bind-html" but none of them works correctly.

I have even tried using direct HTML with ng-bind-html and unsafe as well but no luck there as well.

I have simply tried below HTML but that doesn't work as well.

```
<div ng-repeat="list in lists">
    <div class="content">
        <div ng-bind-html='<p><i><strong>some text</strong></i></p>'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also below doesn't work.

```
<div ng-repeat="list in lists">
    <div class="content">
        <div ng-bind-html-unsafe='<p><i><strong>some text</strong></i></p>'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some modifications in your code.

```
template: "<div class='con'>" +
                "<div><p><i><strong>some text</strong></i></p></div>" +
                "</div>"
```

[AnuglarJS - Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

> The restrict option is typically set to:
>
> - 'A' - only matches attribute name
> - 'E' - only matches element name
> - 'C'   - only matches class name

In your directive, you have this restriction: `restrict: "EA"`, then you can use as element:

`<my-directive></my-directive>`.

```js
(function() {
  angular.module('my.directive', [])
    .directive("myDirective", function() {
      return {
        restrict: "EA",
        scope: false,
        template: "<div class='con'>" +
          "<div><p><i><strong>some text</strong></i></p></div>" +
          "</div>"
      };
    })
    .controller("Controller", ["$scope",
      function($scope) {
        $scope.title = "my-directive";
        $scope.lists = [{
          "id": 1,
          "text": "1"
        }, {
          "id": 2,
          "text": "2"
        }];
      }
    ]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="my.directive">
  <div data-ng-controller="Controller">
    <h1 data-ng-bind="title"></h1>

    <div data-ng-repeat="list in lists">
      <div class="content">{{list.id}}
        <my-directive></my-directive>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: jsFiddle]

---

**Update:** Using `ngSanitize`:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

In your current markup, you need to add double quoutes `"`.

```
<div data-ng-bind-html="'<p><i><strong>some text</strong></i></p>'"></div>
```

And add the ngSanitize dependency in your module.

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  angular.module("my.directive", ["ngSanitize"])
    .controller("Controller", ["$scope",
      function($scope) {
        $scope.title = "my-directive";
        $scope.lists = [{
          "id": 1,
          "text": "1"
        }, {
          "id": 2,
          "text": "2"
        }];
      }
    ]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="my.directive">
  <div data-ng-controller="Controller">
    <h1 data-ng-bind="title"></h1>

    <div ng-repeat="list in lists">
      <div class="content">
        <div data-ng-bind-html="'<p><i><strong>some text</strong></i></p>'"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer but I think my question is little bit confusing. I don't think I can simply remove '' from HTML string that I have as that HTML is coming from my service dynamically. I have just hardcoded that value there as to make sure question is less complex. Sorry for confuse here but my point is, if I am getting this HTML values as String on my controller/ on directive from service than how do I render those values as HTML?

Comment: I have edited question again and specified some details so it is less confusing. Thank you for the answer here. Please help further to resolve this. I have tried many stuffs here but no luck yet. Please help.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Sorry for the confusion. I hope this helps. Also, check about the $sce service: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce.